# php preg_replace Replace specific string with specific valus

Tags: php, preg-replace

I studied following example

---

```
$copy_date = "Copyright 1999";
$copy_date = preg_replace("([0-9]+)", "2000", $copy_date);

 here any numeric will be replaced by 2000
```

---

But in following example I am confused !!

How to replace

width="anything" with value 280

Want to Substitute anything that appears after

```
   width="
```

with

```
   width="280"
```

example
      width="481"
will be width="280"

Another example.....

```
 <iframe width="680" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RTcgXcz-_G0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

after preg_replace

should  become

```
  <iframe width="280" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RTcgXcz-_G0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$copy_date = '<iframe width="680" height="480" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/RTcgXcz-_G0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' ;
$pattern = '/width="\d+"/i' ;
$new_style = 'width="280"' ;
$new_copy_date = preg_replace($pattern, $new_style, $copy_date) ;

echo $new_copy_date;
```